# Cmake: custom target executed after all others without dependencies

Tags: cmake

How can I make get target to be executed **at last** every time make is invoked? I don't want it to depends on anything specific. I just want it to execute independently of any other target in the build tree **as last** target.

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(clang_make ALL
  COMMAND python ${CLANG_MAKE}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

Comment: Assume we have a suboption `AT_LAST`: `add_custom_target(... AT_LAST)`. What will happens if we have two targets: `add_custom_target(A AT_LAST)`, `add_custom_target(B AT_LAST)`?

Comment: Such situtaion could be handled either forbidding to declare twice AT_LAST or by keeping the order of appearance.

Comment: if this is a feature proposal (which it sounds like, since you know that exactly what you are looking for doesn't exist), move it to [the cmake discourse site](https://discourse.cmake.org/).